# How to synchronize listview and mapview with TabHost in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-mapview, android-tabhost

My scenario is as follow: I'm implementing a tabhost that displays two tabs through **LocalActivityManager**. The first one holds a **ListView** that shows information about a geo-localized position (such distance, address name...), and in the second one, I have a **MapView** implementing [Google's Map API](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup) that shows the respective items within the first activity. I can't implement both activities as one, in same view, because the two extends from different classes (the first one has a parent that creates a custom menu and the second one comes from MapView), so the option to do all things in one activity is not available.

My issue is: having a lazy-load (load content in demand, when user scrolls to the end of the list) feature in the first activity, how can I synchronize its items in the MapView activity, using the TabHost methods?

I've stated with some complex solutions already, such using **BroadcastReceiver** or creating AIDL, but I'm looking for the simplest possible solution. I'm not seeking for code itself but a plan to do this task.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thik in this case you need to implement listener pattern, for example

```
 public interface MapDataLoadingListener{
    public void onMapDataLoaded(List<MapData> dataList);
}

public class YourListActivity extends Activity{

    ...

    // somewhere you push yoy lazy load task
    UpdateListTask task = new UpdateListTask();
    task.setMapDataListener(// your map activity)
    task.execute();
    ...
}


public class YourMapActivity extends MapActivity implements MapDataLoadingListener {

     ...

     public void onMapDataLoaded(List<MapData> dataList){
        updateMap(dataList); 
     }

    ...

    private void updateMap(List<MapData> dataList){
        ...
    }

}


public class UpdateListTask extends AsyncTask {

    private MapDataLoadingListener mapDataListener;

    public void setMapDataListener(MapDataLoadingListener mapDataListener){
        this.mapDataListener = mapDataListener;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
       mapDataListener.onMapDataLoaded((List<MapData>) result)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Georgy,
I've already solved this by using the parent Activity (the activity that extends from ActivityGroup) and a combination of the methods Activity:getParent() and Activity:getActivity(StringId) to pass data with a flow-type of [child1->parent->child2].
I gonna accept your answer as it is also a very good one. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You are welcome. But keep it mind that ActivityGroup now is deprecated class.